# setting stack size to thread seems to make no difference in android

Tags: java, android

I using following thread api to set stack size , say i am assigning 1 or 64 or some small value so that i can simulate a stackoverflow exception but the value set does not seem to make any difference.

```
Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name, long stackSize)
```

Comment: Platforms often have a minimum stack size, such as 1 page of virtual memory (4096 bytes usually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well documented in the JavaDoc for [Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). Quoting:

> The details of the relationship between the value of the stackSize parameter and the maximum recursion depth and concurrency level are platform-dependent. **On some platforms, the value of the stackSize parameter may have no effect whatsoever.**

Comment: Android is an operating system, whereas a platform is typically a combination of underlying hardware and operating system, so it's unlikely that this will be consistent across android devices. And even if it happens to be the case now, there's no guarantee it will be in the future. You probably should not be relying on the behavior of the stack size parameter for your application.

Answer (score 3):

The javadoc documentation says that you can't expect any certain behavior so you have to experiment.

I haven't ever tested with small numbers, but creating a thread in Android with

```
new Thread(getMainLooper().getThread().getThreadGroup(), 
    myRunnableThatNeedsLotOfStack, "My Thread", 65536)
```

caused that runnable that would get a StackOverflowError when run in the main thread to go through beautifully, so I guess you can set the stack size of a thread to 64K in Android.

Answer (score 1):

The stack size for the main thread is very small and can't be changed. The size varies by the version of Android; see [What is the android UI thread stack size limit and how to overcome it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843357/what-is-the-android-ui-thread-stack-size-limit-and-how-to-overcome-it) . New threads that you create can be given more stack as Karl says in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Android is open source, so questions like this can be quite easily answered without the guesswork some others are suggesting.  Simply put, the stack size is truncated to lie between a minimum (1536 bytes) and maximum (257Kbytes), so using values outside of these ranges will make no difference.  Also, the suggestion that the main thread size is fixed is not entirely true; it is controlled by the -Xss command line option to the VM, which I believe can be set using `adb shell setprop dalvik.vm.extra-opts`.

Comment: You can see how to set this value on my article: https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/how-to-find-stackoverflowerrors-99264e9709f8