# How to get the stack size

Tags: android, stack, stack-overflow

I have a deep hierarchy in my app.
I need to know what is the size of the stack of the device.
Is there a way to know?
in this link: [What is the android UI thread stack size limit and how to overcome it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843357/what-is-the-android-ui-thread-stack-size-limit-and-how-to-overcome-it)
I see that every android version has it's own stack size but I want to make sure and check it on the fly as the app runs on the user device.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a deep hierarchy in my app

That's not a good idea, regardless of stack space. The more views in your hierarchy, the more expensive the rendering process is. Use Hierarchy View to examine your view hierarchy and find ways to remove unnecessary items (e.g., use compound images with `TextView` widgets rather than using separate `ImageView` widgets inside of a `LinearLayout`).

> I need to know what is the size of the stack of the device. Is there a way to know?

There is nothing in standard Java or in Android that will return the stack size.