# Maximum number of LinearLayout's that can be nested in a single XML file?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

What is the maximum number of LinearLayouts that can be nested ? Is it infinite, or is there a limit that Android-studio emphasizes ? Or is that device dependent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

View tree depth is in practice limited by the UI thread stack size that is needed for the recursive traversal of the view tree in measure/draw operations. [The stack size depends on the API level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843357/what-is-the-android-ui-thread-stack-size-limit-and-how-to-overcome-it) and is 8kB, 12kB or 16kB. There isn't a specific number as the depth limit; in practice you'll see `StackOverflowError`s in low-spec devices after a couple dozen nested views or so.

Lint will nag if you have nesting level 10 or deeper in a single layout file. It doesn't analyze the runtime layout hierarchy depth.

Consider keeping your view hierarchies as flat as possible.

Comment: Assume I am creating Linear layouts inside another from Java Code, will the app crash when the stack overflows ?

Comment: Yes. The view hierarchy is in memory regardless of whether you create it in your code or inflate from a layout XML.

Comment: That was a valuable information! Other than developer.google , any other source to get quality and deep info in Android Development ? :)

Comment: do you have any idea about that how many maximum views can we have in a android layout xml? is there any limit or not

Answer (score 3):

> **Deep layouts** - Layouts with too much nesting are bad for performance.
>
> Consider using flatter layouts such as RelativeLayout or GridLayout to
>   improve performance.
>
> **The default maximum depth is 10**.

[Have a read for more information.](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)