# Maximum number of thread Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to know if there is a maximum number of threads that it is possible to run on an Android device. It depends on the type of the device?

Comment: Technically there is no limit,  but at some point having more threads is going to be less efficient than having less. If you want to see a pretty much optimal implementation of a `ThreadPool` look at the source code of the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Lol are you asking for FTC?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As commented by @Xaver Kapeller, you may create as many `Thread`s you want but more `thread` not actually the part of the solution.

A `core`(CPU) in `Processor` will handle only one `Task`(`Process` or `Thread`) at a given time.

so in `Processor` with 1 core will handle one `thread` at a time. so technically no matter how many threads you open for this `processor` it will serve a thread at a given time. All `threads` which are running would be using processor sequentially, utilizing quantum time of processor which only seems to be concurrent.

`Processor` with 2 core will handle 2 `threads` at a time( concurrent execution of two threads).

`Processor` with 4 `core` will handle 4 threads at a time( concurrent execution of four threads.

`Processor` with 8 core will handle 8 `threads` at a time( concurrent execution of eight threads. so on

Comment: For IO bound operations running more threads than cores is still beneficial because most of them can do the waiting in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Maximum number of threads possible to run on an Android device depends on whether the device has a 32-bit processor or a 64-bit processor and [stack size of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843357/what-is-the-android-ui-thread-stack-size-limit-and-how-to-overcome-it). But you will have memory constraints way before you reach the actual maximum limit.

As mentioned in the article [here](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/07/java-what-is-limit-to-number-of-threads.html) you can run tests to determine maximum number of threads you can create in your Android version.